# Spherical curve whose geodesic curvatue is nonnegative.

Tags: differential-geometry

A closed curve $C$ on a unit sphere $S^2 \subset R^3$ has nonnegative geodesic curvature. Then does the curve lie on a certain (closed) hemisphere?

I was trying solve the question. Since the nonnegative geodesic curvature implies the curve is convex, I guess the above question is true. Anyone could get some help>?

Thanks.